# Stat converted into printf of `find` command

Tags: unix, find, printf, posix, stat

What would be the [`find ... printf`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) conversion for the following timestamps returned from the `stat` command?

```
$ stat myfile
[...]
Access: 2019-03-13 01:00:52.918888000 -0700
Modify: 2019-03-13 01:00:52.918888000 -0700
Change: 2020-12-02 00:31:25.958001000 -0800
Birth: -
```

For example, how could I grab those four values in doing something similar to:

```
find .  -printf "%p,%s,Access?,Modify?,Change?,Birth?\n"
```

Finally, what is the use (and meaning) of `Birth` and how could that be empty ?

Comment: Most (or older *n*x systems anyway) don't record a File's Creation date-time (seemingly one thing MS-Windows got right). I would assume that Birth is to allow for the possibility of storing the date/time when a file was first created. So when it is value `-`, the system didn't store it. Sorry, but I don't know the diference between Modify and Change, it seems like those are synonyms, although your sample data shows otherwise. `man find` and search or `%a/%Ak` and `%c/%Ck`. You'll have to interpret the `k` formatting to get the result you want. Good luck.

Comment: You could also do `find . -exec stat '%SpecicalFmtStrForStat\n" {} \;` or similar, then you could capture all the data. Also check if your version of find has a `%m/%Mk` format specifier.